# Unique combinations on dataframe columns based on criteria from one row

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a `data.frame` of more than 200 columns, and have included a subset below including the columns relevant to this question:

```
>df
Variant   Pos     ID    DB.0.count    DB.1.count    sample1    sample2    sample3    sample4    sample5    sample6    sample7    sample8    sample9    sample10 
variant5  1234567 A     5             5             1/0        1/0        1/0        1/1        1/1        0/0        1/0        0/0        1/0        1/1
.         .       .     .             .             F1         F1         F1         F2         F2         F3         F4         F4         F4         F5
```

I would like to:

**1.** Make all possible combinations of the samples1-sample10 columns where each combination contains one sample from each F number, ie each combination contains 5 samples with one sample each from F1, F2, F3, F4, F5.

So in the above instance there would be 18 combinations, for example:

The first combination would be sample1, sample4, sample6, sample7, sample10

The second combination would be sample1, sample4, sample6, sample8, sample10

The third combination would be sample1, sample4, sample6, sample9, sample10

I have played around with `unique`, `duplicated` and `distinct` after reading related posts but haven't got anywhere.

I would then like to output each unique combination to a new `data.frame`, perform counts for each variable in the samples across the samples and output results to new columns and perform a fisher's exact test as below and output to a new column, as below, which the below code should work to do: (fisher's code learnt here:[Fisher's exact test on values from large dataframe and bypassing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928776/fishers-exact-test-on-values-from-large-dataframe-and-bypassing-errors))

```
df.combo.1$pop.0/0.count <- apply(df.combo.1[,6:10], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("0/0",u))==TRUE) )    
df.combo.1$pop.1/0.count <- apply(df.combo.1[,6:10], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("1/0",u))==TRUE) )  
df.combo.1$pop.1/1.count <- apply(df.combo.1[,6:10], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("1/1",u))==TRUE) )  

df.combo.1$pop.0.count <- ( 2*(apply(df.combo.1[,6:10], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("0/0",u))==TRUE) )) + apply(df.combo.1[,6:10], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("0/1",u))==TRUE) ) )
df.combo.1$pop.1.count <- ( 2*(apply(df.combo.1[,6:10], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("1/1",u))==TRUE) )) + apply(df.combo.1[,6:10], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("0/1",u))==TRUE) ) )

res <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df.combo.1)){
table <- matrix(c(df.combo.1[i, 4],    df.combo.1[i, 5], df.combo.1[i, 14], df.combo.1[i, 15]), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
# if any NA occurs in your table save an error in p else run the fisher test
if(any(is.na(table))) p <- "error" else p <- fisher.test(table)$p.value
# save all p values in a vector
res <- c(res,p)
}
df.combo.1$fishers <- res 


>df.combo.1
Variant   Pos     ID    DB.0.count    DB.1.count    sample1    sample4    sample6    sample7    sample10   pop.0/0.count    pop.1/0.count    pop.1/1.count    pop.0.count    pop.1.count     fishers 
variant5  1234567 A     5             5             1/0        1/1        0/0        1/0        1/1        1                2                2                4              6               1.0000
.         .       .     .             .             F1         F2         F3         F4         F5
```

**2.** Finally I want to create a `data.frame` which lists the fisher's exact p-values for each unique combination, as below:

```
>new.df
combo    fishers
1        1.0000
2        1.0000
3        1.0000
4        1.0000
etc
```

I think this entire exercise may require some sort of for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have got a handle on what you want. For the bit that I think you were struggling with in part 1 I used a combination of which and expand.grid to sort out.

For part 2 that was a reasonably easy cbind once the data was arranged on a 1 line per observation basis.

It looks like you are using 2 rows per observation (unless that is just a formatting thing), that makes it really hard (but not impossible, just require more juggling) so I have combined the data onto a single row. That should be a very easy transformation, just append the appropriate columns from every 'second' row onto every 'first' row and then remove every second row.

This could be done more efficiently and neatly but I think this works and should be reasonably easy to extend to other situations.

Regards,
Josh

```
# provided demo data
# Variant   Pos     ID    DB.0.count    DB.1.count    sample1    sample2    sample3    sample4    sample5    sample6    sample7    sample8    sample9    sample10 
# variant5  1234567 A     5             5             1/0        1/0        1/0        1/1        1/1        0/0        1/0        0/0        1/0        1/1
# .         .       .     .             .             F1         F1         F1         F2         F2         F3         F4         F4         F4         F5


# create data frame in long format
test.df <- as.data.frame(t(c("variant5",1234567,"A",5,5,"1/0","1/0","1/0","1/1","1/1","0/0","1/0","0/0","1/0","1/1","F1", "F1", "F1", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F5")))
# ensure as character format
test.df[] <- lapply(test.df, as.character)
# get postions of "F" data
F1.var <- which(test.df =="F1")
F2.var <- which(test.df =="F2")
F3.var <- which(test.df =="F3")
F4.var <- which(test.df =="F4")
F5.var <- which(test.df =="F5")
# get all combinations of the 5 F positions
Fcode.combinations <- expand.grid(F1.var,F2.var,F3.var,F4.var,F5.var)
# create results data frame
df.combo.1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol = 21, nrow = nrow(Fcode.combinations)))
# name variables
names(df.combo.1) <- c("Variant","Pos","ID","DB.0.count","DB.1.count",
                              "F1.sample.pos","F1.result",
                              "F2.sample.pos","F2.result",
                              "F3.sample.pos","F3.result",
                              "F4.sample.pos","F4.result",
                              "F5.sample.pos","F5.result",
                              "pop.0_0.count","pop.1_0.count","pop.1_1.count",
                              "pop.0.count","pop.1.count",
                              "fishers")
# copy in common data
df.combo.1[,1:5] <- test.df[,1:5]
# setup variables based on combination data
for(i in 1:nrow(Fcode.combinations)){
  df.combo.1[i,c(6,8,10,12,14)] <- Fcode.combinations[i,]
  # -10 to correct for the position of the results not the 'F type' data
  cycle.results <- as.numeric(Fcode.combinations[i,] -10)
  df.combo.1[i,c(7,9,11,13,15)] <- test.df[cycle.results]
}

# this is essentially your code with the column reference changed

df.combo.1$pop.0_0.count <- apply(df.combo.1[,c(7,9,11,13,15)], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("0/0",u))==TRUE) )    
df.combo.1$pop.1_0.count <- apply(df.combo.1[,c(7,9,11,13,15)], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("1/0",u))==TRUE) )  
df.combo.1$pop.1_1.count <- apply(df.combo.1[,c(7,9,11,13,15)], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("1/1",u))==TRUE) )  

df.combo.1$pop.0.count <- ( 2*(apply(df.combo.1[,c(7,9,11,13,15)], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("0/0",u))==TRUE) )) + apply(df.combo.1[,c(7,9,11,13,15)], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("0/1",u))==TRUE) ) )
df.combo.1$pop.1.count <- ( 2*(apply(df.combo.1[,c(7,9,11,13,15)], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("1/1",u))==TRUE) )) + apply(df.combo.1[,c(7,9,11,13,15)], 1, function(u) length(which(grepl("0/1",u))==TRUE) ) )

res <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df.combo.1)){
  table <- matrix(as.numeric(c(df.combo.1[i, 4],    df.combo.1[i, 5], df.combo.1[i, 16], df.combo.1[i, 17])), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  # if any NA occurs in your table save an error in p else run the fisher test
  if(any(is.na(table))) p <- "error" else p <- fisher.test(table)$p.value
  # save all p values in a vector
  res <- c(res,p)
}
df.combo.1$fishers <- res 

# create results data
df.combo.1.results <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:nrow(df.combo.1),df.combo.1$fishers))
names(df.combo.1.results) <- c("combo","fishers")
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!